# how to fix dynamic table header while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic table. The table generates automatically when selecting the from, to datepicker dates. How can I fix the table header part on top always when scrolling. And also I need to make it Fluid

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="our_table">
<thead  class="header">
<tr id="dte">
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Add One more table above the table and fix it.

Comment: Would probably be easiest to use a jQuery plugin. Like [this one](http://fixedheadertable.com/)

Comment: Just search in SO with "fixed header on table content". Lot of Answers are coming..

Answer (score 1):

Try with this CSS style:

```
table {
    display: block;
    max-height: 80px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

For a table that adapts to the window size you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/FhZZj/ (although probably not the most elegant solution).
If you resize the window the table gets resized and horizontal/vertical scrollbars appear when needed.

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.container {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
}
table {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking like the below jsfiddle

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th class="month">Month</th>
  <th class="saving">Savings</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
<tr>
  <td>Sum</td>
  <td>$180</td>
</tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>February</td>
  <td>$80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>February</td>
  <td>$80</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td>$100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>February</td>
  <td>$80</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td>$100</td>
</tr>

 </tbody>
  </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h5t98/

Answer (score 0):

Want you want to do is seperate the content of the table from the header of the table. You want only the  elements to be scrolled. You can easially define this seperation in HTML with the  and the  elements. 
Now the header and the body of the table are still connected to each other, they will still have the same width(and same scroll propeties). Now to let them not 'work' as a table anymore you can set the display: block. This way thead and tbody are seperated.

```
table tbody, table thead
{
    display: block;
}
```

Now you can set the scroll to the body of the table:

```
table tbody 
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100px;
}
```

And last, because the thead doesn't share the same width as the body anymore, you should set a static width to the header of the table:

```
th
{
    width: 72px;
}
```

Note that you are also missing some HTML elements. Every row should be in a  element, that includes the header row:

```
<tr>
     <th>head1</th>
     <th>head2</th>
     <th>head3</th>
     <th>head4</th>
</tr>
```

I hope this is what you meant.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UZA4/1/)

Comment: @user3598780: please see jsfiddle i have given, add same css and update you html table code with theader and tbody you will get result you want.

Comment: but we cant give " width: 72px;" because its a dynamic header, and also need to make fluid

Comment: @user3598780: No issues you can remove this or used percentage instated of fixed width.

Comment: ok iam checking...after i will give you a feed back thank you

Comment: @user3598780: Now what is the problem you are facing after changes you made.

Comment: @user3598780 : I updated your fiddle please check I think your problem is solved now. http://jsfiddle.net/S8eDF/5/

Answer (score -2):

I believe if you use AJAX will help you.